# footable pagination not working properly using slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, jquery-ui-sortable, slim-lang, footable

I am using footable for an index page,I am using slim intead of html,but when I click on sorting icon in footable the pagination numbers increasing abrupty.

```
wrapper.wrapper-content.animated.fadeInRight
  .row
    .col-lg-12
      .ibox.float-e-margins
        .ibox-title
         h5 List of Organizations
        .ibox-content  
          table class="footable table table-stripped" data-page-size="10" 
           thead
            tr
             th Organization
             th Type
           tbody
            - @organizations.each do |f|
             tr
              td= f.name
              td= f.type   
           tfoot
            tr
             td colspan="2"
              ul class="pagination pull-right"
javascript:
$(function() {
$('.footable').footable();
});
```

before click on sort icon
[image]
after click on sort icon
[image]

Am I done anything wrong, please let me know thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wrapper.wrapper-content.animated.fadeInRight
  .row
    .col-lg-12
      .ibox.float-e-margins
        .ibox-title
         h5 List of Organizations
        .ibox-content  
          table class="footable table table-stripped" data-page-size="10" 
           thead
            tr
             th Organization
             th Type
           tbody
            - @organizations.each do |f|
             tr
              td= f.name
              td= f.type   
           tfoot
            tr
             td colspan="2"
              ul class="pagination pull-right"
javascript:
  $(function() {
  $('.footable').footable();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add intent for these lines

```
javascript:
  $(function() {
  $('.footable').footable();
  });
```